# Powershell cmdlet for getting cloud services "Configure tab" attributes?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cloud-services

Is there a powershell cmdlet for getting Windows Azure cloud services "Configure tab" attributes info?

Comment: What specific information do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get-AzureDeployment to receive the details of the deployment in the production or staging slot.

If you need to check which PowerShell commands are available for Azure I would recommend you to take a look to this reference page inside MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn495184.aspx